# Calling a data variable within a custom ifelse() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I am trying to write a specialized `ifelse()` function that I want to pass to `dplyr::mutate(across())`. The function should replace NA values in columns specified in `across()` with those in similarly-named columns.

For instance in the following made-up data, I want to replace missing `x_var1` with `y_var1` and missing `x_var2` with `y_var2`:

```
x <- tribble(~x_var1, ~x_var2, ~y_var1, ~y_var2,
             5, 2, 0, 0,
             NA, 10, 8, 0,
             3, NA, 0, 5,
             NA, NA, 7, 9)
```

I have tried constructing the following function:

```
ifelse_spec <- function(var) {
  new_var = paste("y_", str_remove(cur_column(), "x_"), sep = "")
 
  # print(new_var) # just to check new_var is correct 

  ifelse(is.na(var), !!sym(new_var) , var)  # how to call new_var?
}

x %>%
  mutate(across(c(x_var1, x_var2),
                ~ ifelse_spec(.)))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

However, if I run this one-variable case using `ifelse` directly, I get the expected result.

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x_var1),
                ~ifelse(is.na(.), !!sym("y_var1"), .)))
```

How can I construct a custom ifelse statement that will allow me to call a data variable?

Edit: I got the following to work for the many-variable case, but still using `ifelse` and not a different function.

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x_var1, x_var2),
                ~ifelse(is.na(.), eval(sym(paste("y_", str_remove(cur_column(), "x_"), sep = ""))), . )))
```

Comment: I answered with what I think is a cleaner way to approach this problem, but as to why your function doesn't work, it's because `ifelse()` is evaluated within the function's environment and `!!sym(new_var)` (e.g. `"y_var1"`) isn't defined there. You could try evaluating it in its calling frame, adding a `.data` argument to `ifelse_spec`, or rewriting it as a [function factory](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) that returns an expression to be evaluated within `mutate()`, but personally I wouldn't lean so heavily on non-standard evaluation if I didn't absolutely need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce()` is designed for this problem (filling missing values from other columns). You can simplify your one-variable case by using it instead of `ifelse`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

x <- tribble(~x_var1, ~x_var2, ~y_var1, ~y_var2,
             5, 2, 0, 0,
             NA, 10, 8, 0,
             3, NA, 0, 5,
             NA, NA, 7, 9)

x %>% 
  mutate(x_var1 = coalesce(x_var1, y_var1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   x_var1 x_var2 y_var1 y_var2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      5      2      0      0
#> 2      8     10      8      0
#> 3      3     NA      0      5
#> 4      7     NA      7      9
```

You can then use `select()` to generalise this to coalesce across similarly-named columns:

```r
x %>% 
  mutate(x_var1 = do.call(coalesce, select(., ends_with("var1"))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   x_var1 x_var2 y_var1 y_var2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      5      2      0      0
#> 2      8     10      8      0
#> 3      3     NA      0      5
#> 4      7     NA      7      9
```

Finally, use `map_dfc` to apply this function to each column, using pattern matching to extract the "column group" it belongs to:

```
x %>% 
  colnames() %>% 
  str_extract("var[0-9]") %>% 
  set_names(colnames(x)) %>% 
  map_dfc(~do.call(coalesce, select(x, ends_with(.))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   x_var1 x_var2 y_var1 y_var2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      5      2      5      2
#> 2      8     10      8     10
#> 3      3      5      3      5
#> 4      7      9      7      9
```

You will need to adapt `str_extract()` and `ends_with()` to fit the column names in your real data, but I think this should generalise to any reasonable naming scheme. If it's important to apply a custom function to your real data instead of `coalesce()`, it should also be possible to rewrite `map_dfc()` to use it.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about `coalesce` for a while but couldn't figure out how to generalize things. This really helps!